# Evaluate pathparam arguments in Jersey using AspectJ

Tags: java, rest, jersey, aspectj

I have several APIs which retain a parameter "feature" from the url (path param). To avoid retrieving it in each method endpoint (eg.)

```
@GET
public void findAll(@PathParam("feature") String feature);
```

am trying to implement AOP using AspectJ.

Following is the implementation of the Aspect

```
@Aspect
public class FeatureAOP {
@Pointcut("execution(* x.y.z.rest.ModifiersFacadeWrapper.*(..)) && args(feature)")
    public void pointCut(String feature) {
}

@Before("x.y.z.rest.aop.FeatureAOP.pointCut(feature)")
public void parseParams(JoinPoint jp, String feature) {
    Object[] x = jp.getArgs();
    System.out.println("Feature: " + feature);
}
```

}

The above method gives me the value of "feature" in the Aspect class but if I change the method **findAll** to following signature, it doesn't works.

```
 @GET
 public void findAll();
```

What I understand is the control is transferred to the Aspect after the parameters are resolved and removing it from the method definition is failing it.

Doing so, thus takes me to the same point where I have to define all method endpoints with the parameter in its signature. I would like to know if there is a way I can get the **PathParams in the Aspect class without having to define my methods with the designated parameters**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably do it by putting the resolved params in a globally accessible data structure (e.g. a Singleton having some sort of Map or Set), but
I wouldn't recommend that kind of approach. I don't know why you don't like having all the params in your method signatures, but that is the intended way of declaring rest services, e.g.

```
@GET
@Path("{feature}")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getFeature(@PathParam("feature") String feature) {
    return feature;
}
```

This way you don't have to write any code for retrieving the params, the rest library you are using (be it Jersey or a different one) will just do everything for you.

Comment: This is no different than what I have done. See the first piece of code. Am resolving the feature variable at class level and you are suggesting to do it at method. Both do the same, just the implementation is dependent of the requirement. Moreover, what I have asked is resolving the feature pathparam in an AOP advice rather than in the method parameter. Please read the question again.

Comment: So you want to have an aspectj pointcut that is invoked at the entrance of a method, and that accesses some parameters defined at class level, so that you don't have to replicate those parameters in every method signature. Did I get it right this time?

Comment: Just one rectification. Its not about the variable existing at class level but a parameter coming in from the request url. This parameter is being retrieved at class level, i.e., for every path in this class this parameter will be available. For ex: **@Path("{feature:abc|xyz}") Class Something{...}**. So a parameter feature is being resolved from the uri and can be used in any of the methods in class Something.

Comment: @SumitSrivastava Did you ever get this to work? I am trying to do the same with jersey "@Context" and HttpHeader as a class member instead of method param

Comment: @rodney757 Yes, you are doing it right. Add this piece of code,    `@Context`  
`private UriInfo uriInfo;` Use this **uriInfo** value accessible from the target class instance in the AOP advice to retrieve the value of the parameter you are looking for.